# What does the `--system` flag for **adduser** do?

Tags: linux, docker, non-root-user

What is the purpose and benefit of using the `--system` option when adding a
user, or even a group?

I'd like to know why I'm seeing this added to many Docker containers and recommended as a
best practice?

For example sake I'm adding a non-root user to an Alpine Docker container
for use when developing and again for runtime.

The current versions I'm using are:

- adduser version is 3.118, and the [Alpine adduser man](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_new_user#adduser)
- Alpine version is 3.12
- Docker v19.03.13 on Windows 10 (20H2 update)

The man page reads "Create a system user", O.K. but what do you get as a system
user? Or being in a system group when using `addgroup -S`.

I do not have a System Admin background, so I'm not sure what that means and
would like clarity as to when I should use this?

### Some Other Reading

Searching Google has provide some insight but no way to verify what I've read.
That it does not ask you to set a password for the user, but then I can use use
`--disabled-password` for that.

I then found this post here, I got that its for organization purposes, but does
not help me much either. I'm only a little bit more clearm, yet not confident
enough to explain when to use them.

[What's the difference between a normal user and a system user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80277/9071)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

System users are a like normal users but for are set an organizational purpose.
The only difference is :

- **They don't have an expiry date ( no aging set )**
- **Their uids are below 999 like set on /etc/login.defs** (can be changed) :

Also there is Standard System Users which come with the **OS** or with a **package install** most of them have the above attributes ( **Conventional** ):

- The majority of them have /sbin/nologin or /bin/false as a shell
- They have "*" or "!!" in /etc/shadow meaning that none can simply use them.
- And can have attributes that i have shown on the first section.

To check these **standard system users** list :  /usr/share/doc/setup-/uidgid

An example could be by adding **mypapp** user as a system user ; so in case for example we want to setup Identity Access Management policy in our environment that we can automate for all users ; we have to do it only for **system users** based on their **uids** because in case of **mypapp** account expires the application will stop running.

Comment: That example really helps. I never considered that accounts expire if they are not system.

Comment: I also found the Ubuntu docs which help provide a nice reference: [adduser, addgroup - add a user or group to the system](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html). I like how Alpine Linux is minimalist on the software, but not documentation.

Answer (score 2):

for alpine linux.adduser -S will create a system user,who user id is starting at 100,and can not be login.

kong:x:100:65533:Linux User,,,:/home/kong:/sbin/nologin

but it is different when adduser without -S

horward:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/horward:/bin/ash