# Linux Users and Groups

Tags: users

When I do `cat /etc/passwd` I see multiple users but when I type in `ls -l /home` I can see only two users in it.

How to check the issue.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [What's the difference between a normal user and a system user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80277/whats-the-difference-between-a-normal-user-and-a-system-user)

Comment: Can you also see those user's home directories in the output of `cat /etc/passwd`?

Comment: Not all users have home directories inside `/home`.  Also, users do not have to come from `/etc/passwd`.  If you provide some context as to what you are attempting to achieve, we may be able to provide some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The second last field in /etc/passwd is the users home directory - this can be elsewhere
2. Root's home directory is usually in /root (because root  needs to be able to access when stuff is broken and /home may be on a different drive)
3. as per comments, system accounts should NOT have a home directory in /home - they are subject to different security rules and perform different functions than human beings.
4. I have seen instances where a system account has their home dir configured as /home but no directory exists (e.g. syslog on WSL Ubuntu). That's not an issue because this user never logs in / never has interactive sessions
5. Its quite possible to provision a (normal) user account without creating the home directory at the same time.....but have the home directory created the first time the user logs in - this is does with a PAM module.